# the set of all positive (resp. negative) time-like vectors is convex

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

On page 56 of John Ratcliffe's *Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds*, it says that

> **Corollary 1**. The set of all positive (resp. negative) time-like vectors is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I'm confused about this statement. In $\mathbb{R}^{1, 2}$, the light cone is a double cone (i.e. the solution set of $|x_1| = \sqrt{x_2^2 + \vdots + x_n^2}$); I thought a cone is not convex because if we pick two points on the same level on the cone, a line connecting those two points wouldn't be on the cone since the cone is "empty".

Specifically, $(\sqrt{2}, 1, 1)^T$ and $(\sqrt{2}, 1, -1)^T$ are two points on the light cone of $\mathbb{R}^{1, 2}$. Their midpoint is $(\sqrt{2}, 1, 0)^T$ which is not light-like.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Positive time-like vectors form a convex subset, but light-like vectors don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spelling out exactly what all these objects are should clear things up.

You've correctly described the light cone as the solution set of the equation $|x_1| = \sqrt{x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}$.

The positive time like vectors are the solution set of the inequality 
$$x_1 > \sqrt{x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}
$$ 
which forms a convex set.

The negative time like vectors are the solutions of 
$$x_1 < - \sqrt{x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}
$$ 
which also forms a convex set.

And the space like vectors are the solutions of 
$$-\sqrt{x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2} < x_1 < \sqrt{x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}
$$
which does not form a convex set.

Comment: I see. For some reasons I misread the time-like vectors as light-like vectors and caused the confusion. Thanks for the clarification!